All elements hidden when I refresh a second time in Shiny
I have a shiny app where multiple ui elements are generated with a div(id = ... tag. Afterwards, the user can toggle between showing/hiding. I'm noticing a unexpected action, when I click run/Graph a second time, there is no plot. However, if I use the picker and change to another column, I get the graph. But I dont understand why I dont see the graph when I click the actionbutton the second time, but I do when I click the first time.
choices <- colnames(iris)

library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(bslib)
library(glue)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  pickerInput("col_x", "X", choices = choices, multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("run", "Graph"),
  uiOutput("choose_column_ui"),
  
  uiOutput("ui")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  reactive_values <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    cols <- input$col_x
    ggplot_string <- map_chr(cols, ~glue("ggplot(iris, aes(x = {.x}, y  = Species)) + geom_point() + labs(title = '{.x}')"))
    all_plots <-  map(ggplot_string, ~eval(parse(text = .x))) %>% set_names(cols)
    
    # Save all plots to the output
    
    lapply(cols, function(x) output[[x]] <- renderPlot(all_plots[[x]]))
    
    # Generate all the cards
    
    generate_plot_card <- function(column){
      
        hidden(div(id = column,
                   card(
                     card_body(plotOutput(column)), 
                     full_screen = TRUE
                   )
        )
        )
    }
    
    all_cards   <- map(cols, generate_plot_card)
    
    
    new_picker <- pickerInput("choose_column_to_view", "Choose_col", choices = cols, selected = cols[[1]], multiple = FALSE)
    
    output$choose_column_ui <- renderUI(new_picker)
    output$ui <- renderUI(tagList(all_cards))
    
    reactive_values$cols <- cols
  
    
  })
  
  # Observeevent to show/hide
  
  observeEvent(input$choose_column_to_view, {
    
    # Hide everything
    map(reactive_values$cols, ~shinyjs::hide(id = .x))
    # Show 1
    map(input$choose_column_to_view, ~shinyjs::show(id = .x))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Weird! If you select more than one for the first time, then choose more columns it works. It is not working only when you select only one for the first time.

Although in my sure why this is happening, I added an extra argument to the generate_plot_card that hides all cards, except the first one and that seem to solve the problem. I can also remove hidden(), but that results in a quick glitch when loading the plots.
